# Layout in Emulator Different With Layout in Designer

Tags: android, android-studio

I code using Android Studio. I found some problem that layout in emulator and APK (Build APK and run in my gadget) is different with layout when I design in deisgner. What is wrong with my code ? Or is there something I must set ?

Layout in designer :
[image]

Layout in gadget (apk) :
[image]

My XML Code :

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.alfonsus.ebaandroid.Login">

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/etPassword"
    android:layout_width="280dp"
    android:layout_height="41dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Password"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="52dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="113dp" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/etUserId"
    android:layout_width="280dp"
    android:layout_height="41dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="User ID"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="52dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="44dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnLogin"
    android:layout_width="143dp"
    android:layout_height="47dp"
    android:text="Login"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="121dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="194dp" />
```

Comment: post your xml__

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each view in your layout has attributes like these:

> ```
> tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="52dp"
> tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="113dp"
> ```

Any `tools:` attribute will *only* affect what you see in the layout/design preview, and will have **no effect** on what you see when you actually run your app on an emulator or real device.

In your case, these were added when you dragged-and-dropped views into the visual editor (in order to make your life easy; otherwise the views would snap to the top-left corner like you're seeing on a real device). However, you still need to add constraints to each view so that they'll appear correctly when you run your app.

See this link for more information: https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/#add-a-constraint

Note that you must follow item #3:

> 3. Do one of the following:
>
>    - Click a constraint handle and drag it to an available anchor point (the edge of another view, the edge of the layout, or a guideline).
>    - Click Create a connection in the view inspector at the top of the Attributes window.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you are missing some constraints.

Check your android editor/designer layout again, I think you are missing constraints. 
Every view in android must have a vertical and a horizontal constraint.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make each item have a constraint.